# How to generate 15 digit random number using Scala

Tags: scala, scala-gatling

I am new to Scala programming, I want to generate random number with 15 digits, So can you please let share some example. I have tried the below code to get the alpha number string with 10 digits.

```
  var ranstr = s"${(Random.alphanumeric take 10).mkString}"
  print("ranstr", ranstr)
```

Comment: I have tried like this and I got the random number, is there any other way to get the random number? val rannum = Random.between(100000000, 999999999)
  print("rannum", rannum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pay attention to the return type. You cannot have a 15-digit `Int` because that type is a 32-bit signed integer, meaning that it's maximum value is a little over 2B. Even getting a 10-digit number means you're at best getting a number between 1B and the maximum value of `Int`.

Other answers go in the detail of how to get a 15-digits number using `Long`. In your comment you mentioned `between`, but because of the limitation I mentioned before, using `Int`s will not allow you to go beyond the 9 digits in your example. You can, however, explicitly annotate your numeric literals with a trailing `L` to make them `Long` and achieve what you want as follows:

```
Random.between(100000000000000L, 1000000000000000L)
```

Notice that the [documentation for `between`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Random$.html#between(minInclusive:Int,maxExclusive:Int):Int) says that the last number is exclusive.

If you're interested in generating arbitrarily large numbers, a `String` might get the job done, as in the following example:

```
import scala.util.Random
import scala.collection.View

def nonZeroDigit: Char = Random.between(49, 58).toChar
def digit: Char = Random.between(48, 58).toChar

def randomNumber(length: Int): String = {
  require(length > 0, "length must be strictly positive")
  val digits = View(nonZeroDigit) ++ View.fill(length - 1)(digit)
  digits.mkString
}

randomNumber(length = 1)
randomNumber(length = 10)
randomNumber(length = 15)
randomNumber(length = 40)
```

Notice that when converting an `Int` to a `Char` what you get is the character encoded by that number, which isn't necessarily the same as the digit represented by the `Int` itself. The numbers you see in the functions from [the ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com) (odds are it's good enough for what you want to do).

If you really need a numeric type, for arbitrarily large integers you will need to use `BigInt`. One of its constructors allows you to parse a number from a string, so you can re-use the code above as follows:

```
import scala.math.BigInt

BigInt(randomNumber(length = 15))
BigInt(randomNumber(length = 40))
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/03DPiR5DQhKJsPVMmCZogg/64).

Notice that in my example, in order to keep it simple, I'm forcing the first digit of the random number to not be zero. This means that the number 0 itself will never be a possible output. If you want that to be the case if one asks for a 1-digit long number, you're advised to tailor the example to your needs.

Comment: I think the advantage of `Views` over standard collections should also be mentioned here, e.g. `Views` are *non-strict*, thus evaluated only on demand (lazily).

Answer (score 2):

A similar approach to that by Alin's `foldLeft`, based here in `scanLeft`, where the intermediate random digits are first collected into a `Vector` and then concatenated as a `BigInt`, while ensuring the first random digit (see initialization value in `scanLeft`) is greater than zero,

```
import scala.util.Random
import scala.math.BigInt

def randGen(n: Int): BigInt = {
    val xs = (1 to n-1).scanLeft(Random.nextInt(9)+1) { 
        case (_,_) => Random.nextInt(10) 
    }
    BigInt(xs.mkString)
}
```

To notice that `Random.nextInt(9)` will deliver a random value between `0` and `8`, thus we add `1` to *shift* the possibble values from `1` to `9`. Thus,

```
scala> (1 to 15).map(randGen(_)).foreach(println)
8
34
623
1597
28474
932674
5620336
66758916
186155185
2537294343
55233611616
338190692165
3290592067643
93234908948070
871337364826813
```

Answer (score 1):

There a lot of ways to do this.

The most common way is to use `Random.nextInt(10)` to generate a digit between 0-9.
When building a number of a fixed size of digits, you have to make sure the first digit is never 0.

For that I'll use `Random.nextInt(9) + 1` which guarantees generating a number between 1-9, a sequence with the other 14 generated digits, and a `foldleft` operation with the first digit as accumulator to generate the number:

```
  val number =
    Range(1, 15).map(_ => Random.nextInt(10)).foldLeft[Long](Random.nextInt(9) + 1) {
      (acc, cur_digit) => acc * 10 + cur_digit
    }
```

Normally for such big numbers it's better to represent them as sequence of characters instead of numbers because numbers can easily overflow. But since a 15 digit number fits in a `Long` and you asked for a number, I used one instead.

Answer (score 0):

In scala we have `scala.util.Random` to get a random value (not only numeric), for a numeric value random have `nextInt(n: Int)` what return a random num < n. [Read more about random](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-generate-random-numbers-characters-sequences-in-scala/)

First example:

```
    val random = new Random()
    val digits = "0123456789".split("")
    var result = ""
    for (_ <- 0 until 15) {
      val randomIndex = random.nextInt(digits.length)
      result += digits(randomIndex)
    }
    println(result)
```

Here I create an instance of random and use a number from 0 to 9 to generate a random number of length 15

Second example:

```
    val result2 = for (_ <- 0 until 15) yield random.nextInt(10)
    println(result2.mkString)
```

Here I use the yield keyword to get an array of random integers from 0 to 9 and use mkString to combine the array into a string. [Read more about yield](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-for-loop-yield-examples-yield-tutorial/)